# Informatica Workflow Manager : How to control the flow of the workflow based on some condition

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have below scenario that I want to figure out, how to implement.

After Session0, Either Session1.1 or Session1.2 will execute based on Session Variable (Var). I want to execute Session2 only if either Session1.1 Succeeds or Session1.2 Succeeds.

I have tried below solutions :

1. If I simply put Status conditions on Link C and Link D. Session2 does not executed
2. If I put a decision task after Link C and Link D which checks for Status of Session1.1 and Session 1.2 but workflow still does not read the decision task.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The way you added session 2, it will execute only when both 1.1 and 1.2 executed successfully.
You can solve your issue in two ways.
Option 1. using another session 2 shortcut.
Option 2. using a decision task.

1 - Create a shortcut of session 2 and add it after session 1.2 and original to to 1.2.
Mapping should look like this -

```
          | -> sess 1.1 --> sess 2 
sess 0 -->
          | -> sess 1.2 --> sess 2 (shortcut of original sess2)
```

2 - Create a decision task and add it before session 2. The condition will be if(sess1.1.status=succeeded or sess1.2.status=succeeded,1,0). Then join it to sess 2. The link condition will be decision.condition=1.
Mapping should look like this -

```
          | -> sess 1.1 --> |
sess 0 -->                  | -> decision task -link_cond-> sess 2 
          | -> sess 1.2 --> |
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to keep your design as it is (as showed in the picture) and in session 2, you need to select the check box **Treat Input links as- OR**

Note: Assuming Link c has a condition **Sess 1.1 = succeeded** and Link D has a condition **Sess 1.2 = succeeded**